# Firestore Emulator REST API authentication

Tags: firebase, rest, api, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for some confirmation of expected behaviour for the way the Firestore Emulator REST API handles unauthenticated requests as I think I may have found some possible inconsistencies.

I've been playing around with the Firestore Emulator REST API using Postman for a personal project. If I run the Emulator (`firebase emulators:start --only=firestore`), I'm able to make the following requests successfully **WITHOUT** needing to pass any `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header with the request:

- `GET http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/` (Returns all documents)
- `DELETE http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOCUMENT_ID>` (Deletes an individual document)
- `POST http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>` (Creates a new document in a collection)
- `PATCH http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOCUMENT_ID>` (Updates a document)

However, when I try and get a list of collection IDs as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds) using the following request, I get the following error:

- `POST http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents:listCollectionIds`

Response is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Metadata operations require admin authentication.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

If I pass a `Bearer` token, this request will then run successfully. I generated the token using `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` (as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#working_with_google_identity_oauth_20_tokens)).

Please note, I've set my Firestore Rules to allow all reads and writes for all documents to make things simpler for now:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) give details for authentication, however, the context they describe this in is for making requests against `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/` rather than when using the Emulator.

I'd expect all requests to the Emulator API to not require any authentication, but it seems that some do and some do not and I haven't been able to find any other details in the documentation around how the Emulator should work.

At the moment, I'm not sure if this is a bug and I should file an issue on GitHub, or whether it is expected behaviour and I should just pass a `Bearer` token with every request to be safe.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the API is not working the way you expect, file an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches the behavior of the real API. When you send a request without an auth token, you're attempting to authenticate through the security rules system. Certain methods do not support authentication through security rules, because you would probably not want end-users calling them. These are mostly database administration methods, hence the error description. For example, you would not want end-users calling any indexing methods.

`listCollectionIds` is one of these administrative methods. This is also why this feature is [not supported by the web, iOS, and Android SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the fast reply, Juan.