# Firestore Emulator REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

A similar setup as in [Firestore Emulator REST API authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360640/firestore-emulator-rest-api-authentication), I cannot make it work at all.

When using Postman or the browser, I always get `Not Found` as a response, without an error.

My URL is `http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/path/to/doc` and I am certain it is correct. (`GET` on `http://localhost:8080` returns `Ok` if that means anything.)

Also, the iOS app running in the simulator perfectly connects to the emulator via `localhost:8080`.

I doubt it is a rules issue as one would get an error json as detailed in the question linked above.

What does `Not Found` mean at all?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that there's no information for that particular document you are looking for. Is the firebase emulator populated?

Comment: most certainly, yes

Comment: So have you found the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `documents` in the URL path. The correct one should be

`http://localhost:8080/v1/projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/path/to/doc`